# How to adjust text alignment to both corners of a textview

Tags: android, xml, layout

Currently my layout looks like this:

[image]

Layout code:

```
 <TextView
            style="@style/style_textviewsProfile"
            android:id="@+id/textViewBusID"
            android:text="Bus ID:     " />

   <style name="style_textviewsProfile">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    </style>
```

But I want to adjust the text to one and other corner of the textviews, e.g. **Bus ID** to left-most and **as-676** to right-most. What changes will I need in my XML file?

Comment: maybe you need to show yours xml?

Comment: please sir check my latest edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one relative layout with horizontal orientation and add two text views inside it and then configure their orientation.
For example;

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Tiwari Ji"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Aligning one TextView to start of parent, other one to the end of parent should give you the desired result.

You can see what the above code renders on screen:
[Properly Aligned text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqjNv.png)

The same feat can also be achieved using LinearLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name:" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Tiwari Ji"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here I've given equal weight to the TextViews inside the LinearLayout, by giving them `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

And then by giving `android:gravity="right"` ensured that the text inside the layout is aligned towards the end of the right-most edge of the view.

Happy to help, you can ask if you have any queries.